# Setting up a rooftile system with controllers

Tags: workflow

I'd like to make a reusable rooftile system very similar to the one below, but I don't know how you can make those kind of controllers which affect modifiers and rotation (well, I assume that's what it does).

[image]
(found it here: http://visperfect.com/en/model?&id=61&cid=50)

Cany anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: "*The model is ready to use with the Asset managment addon. The model can be used for commercial purposes.*" And it's only 2,-. Don't you want to support the author who provided you with this nice idea? [The answer is [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/index.html).]

Comment: I would, which is why I contacted the site (you can't "just buy" anymore it seems). But what i'm most interested in is learning how to do this myself so i can apply it to a greater variety of custom rooftiles etc.

Comment: That's a shame. In that case, some pointers: Create an array modifiers and right click on the *Amount* input and choose **Add Driver**. Then in the [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#settings) panel choose your control object as a variables *transformation input*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I'm not an expert, I tried for fun a (very) simple driver setup that you could try to adapt-

I created two shapes roughly resembling yours above, here shown with two different materials to help visualization.

[image]

(Note that I locked all "manual" rotation and location transform for those shapes, because I wished to hide the transform tools when they were selected!)

the top brown cylindrical has an array that allows for X replication (fixed count), and has a driver using the X location of a "controlling" mesh (a blue cube, named cube.001, here hidden in another layer)

[image]

the side yellow square shape had two array modifiers, allowing replication (fixed count) on its X and Y local axis, with a driver for each (always to the blue controlling cube, on its X and Z), and also a driver that allows for the rotation on its X, based on the X rotation (limited by constraints) of the blue cube.

[image]

You can add those drivers right clicking on the "count" property, and choosing this menu voice:

[image]

You'll find (for a selected object) this new driver settings in the "graph" editor, selecting "drivers" mode, instead of the default "f-curve"

Here is the overall setup:

[image]

Now, revealing the blue cube (separate layer) allows for "roof tiles" editing: the cube is in  its initial position

[image]

grabbing it along its X, allows for the roof X "expansion"

[image]

then, grabbing the blue cube down on its Z, expands the roof tiles on their Y direction:

[image]

and finally, rotating the blue cube on its X axis allows the roof tile to rotate in the same way, as needed:

[image]

here is an animation showing how it works, and how you can reset it using clear location (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and clear rotation (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)

[image]

and here is the file I used (just a simple example)

[image]

Note: drivers need to automatically run python scripts, so you need to load the file using the "trusted source"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna give this a good look when I have some time :)